# Implementing function links from text in Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt6

I'm trying to implement clickable words in a paragraph in Qt. I want to be able to run a function once a word/sentence is clicked. I have tried using flat buttons along with the text in box layouts and it functions but the buttons stick out too much visually. I am very new to Qt and I don't know what ways I could accomplish this in, thank you for the help.

Happy to clarify if anything is unclear.

Comment: Qt text widgets feature a basic [HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html) support, so just use the standard `<a href="something">...</a>` syntax, if you are using QLabel, connect to the `linkActivated` signal, if you're using QTextEdit you may consider switching to QTextBrowser. In any case, please [edit] your post to clarify your needs and provide a basic [mre] we can base answers upon, as right now the question is too vague.

Comment: Yes I did check out the html syntax but I was uncertain as to how to use it to call functions. I will try to expand on the question a bit more once I'm back at a computer.

Comment: If you don't need editing, use QTextBrowser and connect the [`anchorClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextbrowser.html#anchorClicked) signal to a function that checks for the clicked url, then call the related function based on it.

Comment: Subclassing `QTextEdit` and override `mouseReleaseEvent` might help... However it would definitely be a big deal -- confirming text that the mouse has pressed, handling functions, linking to the anchors, detecting the current `QTextCharFormat`, super it to its parent class,... So, as @musicamante said, you'd better use a `QTextBrowser`. It really rocks.

Comment: @Misinahaiya Actually, it's not that difficult, since QTextEdit already provides [`anchorAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#anchorAt), which doesn't require checking the format: if there is an anchor for a link, it returns its target address, otherwise the string would be empty.